# AWS Sagemaker InvokeEndpoint: operation: Endpoint of account not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I've been following this guide here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/building-an-nlu-powered-search-application-with-amazon-sagemaker-and-the-amazon-es-knn-feature/

I have successfully deployed the model from my notebook instance. I am also able to generate predictions by calling `predict()` method from `sagemaker.predictor`.

This is how I created and deployed the model

```
class StringPredictor(Predictor):
    def __init__(self, endpoint_name, sagemaker_session):
        super(StringPredictor, self).__init__(endpoint_name, sagemaker_session, content_type='text/plain')

pytorch_model = PyTorchModel(model_data = inputs, 
                             role=role, 
                             entry_point ='inference.py',
                             source_dir = './code', 
                             framework_version = '1.3.1',
                             py_version='py3',
                             predictor_cls=StringPredictor)

predictor = pytorch_model.deploy(instance_type='ml.m5.large', initial_instance_count=4)
```

From the SageMaker dashboard, I can even see that my endpoint and the status is "in-service"

If I run `aws sagemaker list-endpoints` I can see my desired endpoint showing up correctly as well.
My issue is when I run this code (outside of sagemaker), I'm getting an error:

```
import boto3
sm_runtime_client = boto3.client('sagemaker-runtime')
payload = "somestring that is used here"
response = sm_runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName='pytorch-inference-xxxx',ContentType='text/plain',Body=payload)
```

This is the error thrown

```
botocore.errorfactory.ValidationError: An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Endpoint pytorch-inference-xxxx of account xxxxxx not found.
```

This is quite strange as I'm able to see and run the endpoint just fine from sagemaker notebook and I am able to run the `predict()` method too.

I have verified the region, endpoint name and the account number.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the exact same error, I've just fixed mine by setting the correct region.

> I have verified the region, endpoint name and the account number.

I know that you have indicated that you have verified the region, but in my case, the remote computer had another region configured. So I just ran the following command on my remote computer

```
aws configure
```

And once I set the key ID and secret key again, I set the correct region and the error was gone.

Comment: super, that solved my problem

Comment: I am still facing this issue.. confirmed the credentials & region, etc. PS: running on cloud9 & streamlit